# Why isnt my Proc Gen dungeon working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I got the first room of my procedural dungeon working, or rather one room, however I dont know where to go from here to create multiple rooms as I cant just use CreateRoom again for some reason. If anyone could help I would appreciate it very much, Im new to coding so it's hard for me to understand why I cant use the same function while changing the starting position.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProcGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] floorTiles;
    public GameObject[] wallTiles;
    public float ceilingHeight;
     public Vector3 roomSpawn = new Vector2(0, 0);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Instantiate(floorTiles[0]);
        CreateRoom(Random.Range(2,7), Random.Range(2,9), roomSpawn);
        //CreateRoom(2,2, new Vector2(50, 50));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    void CreateRoom(int width, int length, Vector2 position)
    {
        // FLOOR and Roof GENERATION
        int tileWidth = (int)floorTiles[0].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
        // truncate the position that was passed in
        Vector2 firstPos = new Vector2(Mathf.Floor(position.x), Mathf.Floor(position.y));
        Vector2 tilePos = firstPos;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                Instantiate(floorTiles[Random.Range(0, floorTiles.Length)], new Vector3(tilePos.x, 0, tilePos.y), Quaternion.identity);
                Instantiate(floorTiles[0], new Vector3(tilePos.x, ceilingHeight, tilePos.y), Quaternion.Euler (0f, 0f, 180f));
                tilePos += new Vector2(tileWidth, 0);
            }
            tilePos = new Vector2(firstPos.x, tilePos.y);
            tilePos += new Vector2(0, tileWidth);
        }


        // WALL GENERATION
        float rotation = 90;
        
        Vector2 wallPos = firstPos;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(wallTiles[Random.Range(0, wallTiles.Length)], new Vector3(wallPos.x, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0)));
            wallPos += new Vector2(tileWidth, 0);
        }

        rotation += 90;
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(wallTiles[Random.Range(0, wallTiles.Length)], new Vector3(0, 0, wallPos.y), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0)));
            wallPos += new Vector2(0, tileWidth);
        }

        rotation += 90;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(wallTiles[Random.Range(0, wallTiles.Length)], new Vector3(i * tileWidth, 0, firstPos.y + ((width - 1) * tileWidth)), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0)));
            wallPos += new Vector2(tileWidth, 0);
        }

        rotation += 90;
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(wallTiles[Random.Range(0, wallTiles.Length)], new Vector3((length - 1) * tileWidth, 0, i * tileWidth), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0)));
            wallPos += new Vector2(0, tileWidth);
        }
    }

    int CalculateAddition(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

Like I said I tried to use CreateRoom again and it overlayed it on top of spawn again, but the walls didnt correctly place like I wanted them to, they seem to be placing at the spawn again.

Comment: well,  one thing obviously is that you start in a random point and make a random room. Fine.   Why you cant call it again, that you have to tell us why what happens.. my guess is it doesnt know where the old one is, so makes a new room but maybe they overlap.. So, likely need to keep a track of where rooms are..